# atomパッケージplatformio-ide-terminalのworking Directory設定が機能しない

Tags: windows, atom-editor

Atom上でPowershellを使いたくてplatformio-ide-terminalをインストールしたのですが、Working Directoryの設定をProjectやActive fileにしてみても起動したPowershellのディレクトリがホームディレクトリになってしまいます。
公式のgitのissueとかを見てみたのですが、あまり英語は得意ではなく解決方法は見つかりませんでした。
どうすればうまくいくでしょうか？

### やってみたこと

設定のTogglesのチェックをすべて外してみたが変化はなかった。
apmからインストールしてみたが変化はなかった。
teminal-plusをインストールしてみたが、実行しても画面が黒のまま文字が表示されなかった。

### バージョン

Windows10
atom : 1.32.2
apm : 2.1.2
platformio-ide-terminal : 2.8.4